# iOS binary rejected due to crash on launch, cannot recreate, only have error log to go from

Tags: ios, error-handling, libgdx

I submitted my app to iOS the other day and unfortunately it got rejected. Apparently it crashed on launch. The game runs perfectly on Android, and I cannot re-create this "crash on launch" on iOS. For me it just works. But my test-environment is limited to an iphone 5 and emulators.

Could someone please take a look at these error logs and see if they can find something?

Error log: [Here](http://a281.phobos.apple.com/us/r30/Purple118/v4/fd/8b/c9/fd8bc9b5-2e37-0669-e78a-cee1bf8a08fe/attachment-5439759654382475181crashlog-E438FBF4-BF50-4517-BB48-C0301206BCFA.txt?downloadKey3=1501197446_c912a998ee1a0dadf1494214e6f0de3a)

If you know why, or have any ideas/suggestion, please let me know.

Comment: This "0x8badf00d" is a special code that appears in a crash log when your app is not being responsive, either on launch or coming to the foreground (maybe other times too).  You need to look up how to symbolicate a crash to see what's happening on thread 0; with that information you may be able to move work to the background or otherwise understand the problem.

Comment: @PhillipMills Thanks for you advice. Ill keep trying

Comment: If anyone has had a similar problem please share anything you found.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "keep trying".  If you turn the crash into readable symbols, it **will tell you** where in your code things went wrong.

Comment: @PhillipMills Okay I didn't know that, could you please forward me somewhere that they explain how to do this? not sure what to search for.

Comment: @PhillipMills Think I found instructions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1460892/symbolicating-iphone-app-crash-reports

Comment: Also, Apple's tech note on crash reports: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2151/_index.html (Much easier, assuming you have the distribution archive.)

Comment: Running command `atos -arch arm64 -o 'Space Pack.app.dSYM/Contents/Resources/DWARF/Space Pack' -l 0x0000000100e55564 0x100070000` returns `0xff21aa9c (in Space Pack)`. Not sure what to make of that.

Comment: @Green_qaue have you solved the issue?

Comment: @SaurabhJain No, waiting to get access to an iPhone so I can symbolicate. Not working through terminal so.

Answer (score 0):

According to log your exception code **0x8badf00d** . This code indicates that an application was terminated by iOS because a watchdog timeout occurred. Basically, the application took too long to launch, terminate, or respond to system events.